# Cannot return type IQueryable or IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, wcf, entity-framework

Since I cannot return either of these types from a Linq to Entities query, I am sticking with returning a List.

On return from the DB call (which is in a separate WCF service or DLL), the code in the Controller fails because the **dbcontext connection is closed**.

Note the code in the following. For both IEnumerable and IQueryable, the data does not come back because of the above description.

### Method in MVC Controller

```
// Controller
IEnumerable<ProjectDescription> projectDdl = db.GetProjectDropDownList().AsEnumerable();
// Error coming back because dbcontext connection was closed.
ViewBag.ProjectsCust = new SelectList(projectDdl, "ProjectId", "Name");
```

### Method in WCF service or DLL

```
// WCF Service or DLL 
public IEnumerable<ProjectDescription> GetProjectDropDownList()
{
    try
    {
        //IQueryable<ProjectDescription> project = null;

        using (YeagerTechEntities DbContext = new YeagerTechEntities())
        {
            DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            DbContext.Database.Connection.Open();

            IEnumerable<ProjectDescription> project = DbContext.Projects.Select(s =>
                new ProjectDescription()
                {
                    ProjectID = s.ProjectID,
                    Description = s.Description
                }
            );


            return project;
        }


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

I even tried the following establishing a DbContext instance before the DB call which still didn't work actually trying to pass down the DbContext to the DB method.

### Controller:

```
DbContext = new YeagerTechEntities();
IEnumerable<ProjectDescription> projectDdl = db.GetProjectDropDownList(DbContext).AsEnumerable();
ViewBag.ProjectsCust = new SelectList(projectDdl, "ProjectId", "Name");

DbContext.Dispose();
```

### DB method:

```
public IEnumerable<ProjectDescription> GetProjectDropDownList(YeagerTechEntities DbContext)
{
    try
    {
        //IQueryable<ProjectDescription> project = null;


            DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            DbContext.Database.Connection.Open();

            IEnumerable<ProjectDescription> project = DbContext.Projects.Select(s =>
                new ProjectDescription()
                {
                    ProjectID = s.ProjectID,
                    Description = s.Description
                }
            );


            return project;
        }


    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

The only thing that worked besides using List was to actually place the DB method inside the Controller, which obviously is not good practice whatsoever.

Here is the List convention that works fine:

### Controller:

```
IEnumerable<ProjectDescription> projectDdl = db.GetProjectDropDownList();
                ViewBag.ProjectsCust = new SelectList(projectDdl, "ProjectId", "Name");
```

### DB method:

```
public List<ProjectDescription> GetProjectDropDownList()
{
    try
    {
        using (YeagerTechEntities DbContext = new YeagerTechEntities())
        {
            DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            DbContext.Database.Connection.Open();

            IEnumerable<ProjectDescription> project = DbContext.Projects.Select(s =>
                new ProjectDescription()
                {
                    ProjectID = s.ProjectID,
                    Description = s.Description
                }
            );

            List<ProjectDescription> myProjects = new List<ProjectDescription>();

            myProjects = project.ToList();

            return myProjects;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

If anyone can explain to me what the correct model should be when using IQueryable or IEnumerable, that would be fine. However, after reading this link, it definitely seems like List is the way to go:
[IEnumerable vs IQueryable for Business Logic or DAL return Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677722/ienumerable-vs-iqueryable-for-business-logic-or-dal-return-types)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason why your code failed when using IEnumerable/IQueryable is because the EF query is deferred; that is to say it doesn't actually get executed against the database until you start to enumerate (`foreach`, etc) or "materialise" (`ToList()`, etc) the results.

- Therefore because you create an effectively temp `DbContext` with your `using{}`, the `IEnumerable` that you pass out of the function is a landmine - the underlying DbContext ceases to exist after the using block, and any attempt to enumerate or materialise the collection will fail.
- Even when you created the `DBContext` without a using block, you then went ahead and `Dispose`'d of it before you executed the query - hence getting the same error.
- This is one of the main reasons for not returning `IQueryable` from a DAL/Repository - because the recipient *cannot know* if the underlying context that the query relies on has been closed before they try to consume the results. `IEnumerable` is much better (`List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` of course) and IMHO List is even better because it forces you to return a fully materialised collection and makes it clear to the caller that the result is not connected to the database any more.
- So the working version that you have is probably fine - create your context, execute the query *and then immediately materialise it* which executes the actual SQL and then disconnects the result set from the database. So that pattern will work fine for you.
- However I would recommend looking at having things like DbContext injected for you using an IoC container such as [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) as it frees you from having to worry about the lifecycle of your DbContexts.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Also having DbContext inject into IOC container, would it still work if we were to use the using block? I thought as soon as you come out of the using block, the Dispose() get called and the context get destroyed?

Comment: Glad it made sense!@Raj, if you used an IoC containter to inject the DbContext, you wouldn't have a using block - one thing that happens when you use Dependency Injection, is that you surrender control of the lifecycle of injected objects - in this case the IoC Container makes the choice when to dispose of the DbContext. It's a small price to pay!

Comment: +1 Good points.  More of a landmine instead of a timebomb, as it does not explode until stepped on.

Answer (score 2):

As you already knows, your `DbContext` enables you to query your database and so it has to be alive when SQL requests are sent to your SGBD.

The key point here is to know exactly how [IQueryable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.linq.iqueryable.aspx) works :

> The IQueryable interface inherits the IEnumerable interface so that
>   if it represents a query, the results of that query can be enumerated.
>   Enumeration causes the expression tree associated with an IQueryable
>   object to be executed. The definition of "executing an expression
>   tree" is specific to a query provider. For example, it may involve
>   translating the expression tree to an appropriate query language for
>   the underlying data source.

Which means that as long as your Linq query has not been enumerated (with .ToList() or foreach), no query is sent to the database. The execution is deferred!

In your first attempt, you're :

- Calling the `GetProjectDropDownList` method
- Returning an `IEnumerable` (which is a Ling query) without "enumerating" it
- Disposing the `DbContext`
- Enumerating your Linq query through `new SelectList` when your view is generated but... Your `DbContext` has already been disposed at that time.

The same applies for your second attempt, the `DbContext` is disposed a little bit later but also already disposed when the view is generated.

In your last attempt, everything works fine because your `DbContext`is still alive when you're enumerating your Linq query (with `project.ToList();`)

In my opinion, isolating your `DbContext` calls and instances into a [Data Access Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748993/design-pattern-for-data-access-layer) and returning Lists or simple disconnected objects is not a bad practice at all.