How to write a function, which should encapsulate individual code?
I want to write a class which should handle my database connection.
I'm struggling to find a solution for my problem.
I have functions which are declaring the cmdSQLite string and opening the connections. Especially for some use cases, where I have to manipulate the data at the time it's being read (e.g. when using comboboxes, populating treeviews or having to convert only some of the data).
I would like to use a reader function like this: it should check the DbType, then open the reader + read the data from the reader. At the end it should close the connection.
The commented part in the middle (marked with /* */) should be the code, which is different every time, as this code depends e.g. on the SQL string entered earlier.
public object getData()
{
    switch(DbConn.DbType)
    {
        case 1:
            using (SQLiteDataReader reader = cmdSQLite.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                        /*  //Inject custom code and RETURN DATA How?
                        cb_AG.Items.Add(reader.GetValue(2).ToString());

                        if (dtProj.Rows[0][3].ToString() == reader.GetValue(0).ToString())
                        {
                            cb_AG.SelectedIndex = i;
                        }

                        i++;  */
                  }
            }

            connSQLite.Close();
            return object; //Object has to be declared in given Textblock

        case 2: //same, with MySQL
            [...]

        default: 
            return null;
    }
}

Would be Object object = new Function(); a solution? But how to pass the function from the outside? Are there any pitfalls, which could be dangerous, when using that solution?
Or is there something better? I was also thinking about interfaces and delegates, but I'm not sure, if they will really fit into my class.
I'm stuck there as I don't know, which 'basic' model I should use, which also won't destroy the repairability of the code.

there are known patterns and DI to handle DAL, also check this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748993/design-pattern-for-data-access-layer

also, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058497/dependency-injection-with-netcore-for-dal-and-connection-string

As a side note, be aware that there is overhead involved in opening a database connection on a server.  Assuming you're doing multiple requests, it would be better to open the connection once and reuse it.
